# What's the purpose of the bld and bin folders in a Windows 8 JavaScript project?

Tags: javascript, windows-8, winjs

I know that the files in the *bld* and *bin* folders are not what are being referenced by the deployed app (I can tamper with them and they have no effect on the app the next time I launch it from the start screen), so what are they for and what's the difference between the *bld* and *bin* folder?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They're temporary build directories for the process of the application being "built". However, the *bin* directory is the deployment directory, and technically speaking you should be able to edit and have the next instance started pick up those changes.

When I tested this just now with the *bin* directory, it did pick up those changed once I terminated the app, and started again from the start page